# Chrome Headless 83.0.4103.116 (Linux x86_64) ERROR Disconnected, because no message in 30000 ms., Angular 8

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-jasmine, karma-coverage

I have 746 test cases, but when i am trying to run the test cases using the command below:

```
"ng test --browsers='CustomChromeHeadless' --code-coverage=true --watch=false --source-map=false",
```

it gives error as below, after executing some random number of test cases.

```
Chrome Headless 83.0.4103.116 (Linux x86_64) ERROR
  Disconnected, because no message in 30000 ms.
```

**package.json**

```
"karma": "^5.1.0",
"karma-chrome-launcher": "^3.1.0",
"karma-cli": "^2.0.0",
"karma-coverage": "^2.0.2",
"karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^3.0.3",
"karma-jasmine": "^3.3.1",
"karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.5.4",
"karma-junit-reporter": "^1.2.0",
```

**karma.config.js**

```
// Karma configuration file, see link for more information
// https://karma-runner.github.io/0.13/config/configuration-file.html

module.exports = function (config) {
  config.set({
    basePath: '',
    frameworks: ['jasmine', '@angular-devkit/build-angular'],
    plugins: [
      require('karma-jasmine'),
      require('karma-chrome-launcher'),
      require('karma-jasmine-html-reporter'),
      require('karma-junit-reporter'),
      require('karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter'),
      require('karma-junit-reporter'),
      require('@angular-devkit/build-angular/plugins/karma'),
    ],
    client: {
      clearContext: false, // leave Jasmine Spec Runner output visible in browser
    },
    files: ['src/environments/testRunner.js'],
    preprocessors: {},
    mime: {
      'text/x-typescript': ['ts', 'tsx'],
    },
    junitReporter: {
      useBrowserName: false,
      outputDir: 'coverage',
      outputFile: 'TESTS-results.xml', // sonarqube is looking for TESTS-*.xml
    },
    coverageIstanbulReporter: {
      dir: require('path').join(__dirname, 'coverage'),
      reports: ['html', 'lcovonly', 'clover'],
      fixWebpackSourcePaths: true,
    },
    reporters:
      config.angularCli && config.angularCli.codeCoverage
        ? ['progress', 'coverage-istanbul', 'junit']
        : ['progress', 'kjhtml'],
    port: 9876,
    colors: true,
    logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,
    autoWatch: true,
    browsers: ['CustomChromeHeadless'],
    customLaunchers: {
      CustomChromeHeadless: {
        base: 'ChromeHeadless',
        flags: ['--no-sandbox', '--disable-gpu', '--disable-dev-shm-usage', '--headless'],
      },
    },
    singleRun: true,
  });
};
```

Also, sometimes i get random test case failed, which passes when i rerun the test.

[image: ChromeHeadless getting disconnected]

Comment: Any success on this?